# How Can I Disable Wordpress Theme Self-Update?

Tags: themes, css

Q:I have a wordpress theme and i want to make some changes on the styles and css files but every time I make changes , after refreshing the page the custom styles are gone.

Even I delete the theme css file and made another one but again it recovers itself.

I mean the theme recreate the css files after refreshing.

How Can I Disable it that the theme Doesn't recover the files and styles.

1.I Change The Name of the Theme but it doesn't work.

2.I Change the get_Stylesheet_uri() but again nothing happens .

I Am using the theme on localhost

Edit:I turn off my internet and when i checked again it happens , i think it's in the codes.

Comment: WordPress themes don't update on every page load. Something else is wrong. Are the styles not appearing? Or are they literally being deleted from the style.css file?

Comment: @JacobPeattie as a example i change the font family in my theme css and then i refresh the page and all dissapeard and when i back to notepad++ it says that the file changed do you want to reload? it means it the file changed to back.

Comment: Well that's not how WordPress is supposed to work, unless you're using a theme or plugin that writes to the stylesheet.

Comment: @JacobPeattie what it means? is there any way that i can solve this?